# Antialiasing issue with youtube videos in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, antialiasing

1. Get the iframe from youtube.
2. Paste youtube-iframe to simple html page.
3. Create a page with iframe to this page.

= you get a page with iframe that contains youtube-iframe.

1. Set the last iframe (iframe, that contains youtube-iframe) style:
   `-webkit-transform: 0.5`

= you get a page with smaller iframe that contains youtube-iframe.

-> http://jsfiddle.net/43U3m/1/

All page (your iframe) became not-antialiased. You can see it on text and image in jsfiddle example.

Is there any way to fix it?